# UITableView programmatically on runtime

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I want to do the following:

I have to create a UITableView at the runtime depending upon some conditions, at the run time only I will come to know from which database table the data has to be pulled from to be presented in the UITableView to make this problem more complicated I will have to create a custom UITableViewCell also at the run time.

I am not able to think how do I create this UITableView and then how do I create all those delegate method at the runtime.

I will give some more background that will help understand this problem, I am making a request to my server, and the server returns me an xml response object, after parsing I figure out that I have to present a table to the user on a particular action and the table will have custom cell, for which the values are available in the xml response object.

Please help I have been trying to figure out this thing for a while now.

EDIT:

I will try to explain in a different way, if that helps people understand my problem.

Hi, I want, to do the following:

On the runtime(which means while my app is running) I have to create a UITableView depending upon some conditions(some action taken by the user), I will make a server call and will get the data for the UITableView.

There has to be a a custom UITableViewCell for this UITableView that I have created at the run time, I will get the information for the custom UiTableViewCell also at the run time.

So basically I don't have any thing at the compile time except that I may have to create a UITableView and a custom UITableViewCell.

I am trying to figure out that how do I create the delegate method and custom UITableViewCell at the run time.

One thing that I thought was to have a default class with all the delegate method and when I create UITableView at the run time associate this class as the delegate for the newly created UITableView, let me know if this is an ok solution.

But how do I associate the custom UITableViewCell to this delegate method at the run time is still an issue.

Comment: Your question is really confusing I am not understanding what exactly do you want to do? It is not that difficult to create UI dynamically you are making it more tough I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the new values that you would come to know during the run time and then use `[tableViewObject reloadData];`

The delegate functions will remain the same. In IB just place the UITableView wherever you want and set the delegate and datasource to the file owner. Set the hidden property to yes by checking the check box.

Once the user does some action change the hidden property in the action function as `tableViewObject,hidden = NO;`

Your delegate methods will look like

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
   return [tableData count];
  }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"acell"];
      if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"acell"] autorelease];
      }
      cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
      return cell;
   }
```

In this `tableData` will be your datasource that could be declared in your .h file. In the function that captures the action of the user, you can get the data from the server and add it to the tableData and then as suggested earlier call `[tableViewObject reloadData];`

Comment: Hi devsri, I don't have a table in the first place so I am not clear that how should is reloadData, the very first thing that I have to do is to create a table based on come condition on the runtime. So as I don't have any table, I don't have any delegate also, are you suggesting that I should create a delegate and keep it and then in the run time when I create a table associate that delegate with my newly created table, but the problem there is i will need a custom UITableViewCell also that will be decided in the runtime as well.

Comment: hi Yogesh..... I suppose, I mentioned that you can create a table and set its property as hidden. It will be only visible when you want during the run time. And about the cell formatting at run tim that could be done in the third function - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

I myself used the same concept and it worked.

Comment: the table would be created but the data could be fed at run time and the visibility of the table can also be set at the run time. so it will behave like the table being created at run time.

Comment: ok so basically you are saying create everything at the time of coding, populate it at the run time only if it is needed, sounds good, let me try out

Comment: and one more thing do sccept or vote up the answer if it helped u

Answer (score 0):

After you are done parsing the reply from the server you should call

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

And in the method `[tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`

Depending upon some values or identifiers that you have for each database load values from that particular database and render it into tableView cell.

Comment: Hi SPatil, I guess I was not able to explain the question properly, I don't have a table already, basically I have to create the table itself based on the some condition, so the first thing that I have to do is to create the table and then populate the table. And on the method          [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] I cannot write anything I can call that method and it will give me the cell at a given index.